# wanting to extend my desktop flatscreen to my laptop screen but have questions

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

Following the question and answer session regarding PC having dvi monitor output and ? also HDMI output but wanting to use another monitor which uses VGA and how to do..

I am looking for something similar in that my ?graphics card on my desktop pc has a vga / hdmi / dvi-d.  I am currently using the vga output to the flatscreen monitor.

My issue is I want to also use my laptop that has a vga port to extend my desktop monitor for work requiring larger monitor space.

Looking at the answers provided to the previous conversation, I am wondering if I have purchased a hdmi to dvi-d cable and ran it was the desktop pc to the flatscreen monitor, Would the monitor work  AND then.. 
purchase a vga to vga cable and run it from my laptop vga port to the vga port on the flatscreen monitor... would this allow me to use my laptop screen and my desktop flatscreen monitor as one large monitor (extend) 
OR would I run the vga cable from the laptop to the vga output on the back of my desktop pc?
I am totally confused but want to make something fairly cost efficient to make this work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a broken laptop with a working lcd you can buy something like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/M-NT68676-2A-HDMI-DVI-VGA-Audio-LCD-LED-Screen-Controller-Board-Diy-Monitor-Kit-/110977522562) and turn it into a working monitor with vga port.

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work.  The monitor's VGA port is essentially designed to take "input" and display it;  it doesn't "output" the display that you see.  [The terms I'm using are just to try to make it understandable.]

And your laptop's display doesn't work like a conventional monitor;  your laptop's VGA connector is meant to send a signal -out- to another monitor, not used to "input" information to the laptop's display.